# Does PayPal Standard automatically retry to charge the client if a payment fails?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have to integrate PayPal Standard Payments in my Saas for a monthly subscription.

I found a few tips in the PayPal documentation about using API but it's not my case.

If after a few months a payment fails because the client has no money, does it automatically retry to charge the client in the next days or should I set a custom field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variable [**sra**](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) when set to 1 , PaYPal will try to collect the payment two more times before canceling the subscription.
More information on [Recurring Payments Reattempts](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADFC002A6)

> How PayPal Reattempts Failed Recurring Payments

*PayPal reattempts to collect recurring payments three days after the day on which recurring payments fail. If the first reattempt to collect a recurring payment fails, PayPal waits 5 days to reattempt a second time. If the second reattempt fails, PayPal cancels the subscription.*

Comment: I am using Paypal's Subscription API, which documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/ I am also confused how Paypal retry for failed Payment of Subscription, I raised a question regarding this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57727814/5026957 Can you please have a look at it