# Paypal recurring payment reattempts: IPN callback flow for failed payments, and subscription cancellation?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment, recurring-billing

I have a bog-standrad Paypal subscription -button installation, with an IPN callback flow. One bleeding point of this setup for the past 24 months has been the instant subscription cancellation upon lack of available funds; which, statistically, happens with moderate frequency in the target market I'm currently selling to.

So, current IPN flow is: subscr_signup -> [Nx] subscr_payment -> subscr_cancel/subscr_failed [terminate subscription].

According to a previous SO question: [retry to charge the client if a payment fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546558/does-paypal-standard-automatically-retry-to-charge-the-client-if-a-payment-fails):

> There is a variable sra when set to 1 , PaYPal will try to collect the payment two more times before canceling the subscription. More information on [Recurring Payments Reattempts](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADFC002A6)

I suspect using this would drastically reduce "churn-by-payment-issue" problem, and would like to implement this.

My question is, what is the IPN callback flow for these endgame situations? That is, for "payment failed, will retry", VS "payment failed, subscription terminated" , specifically, what order, and txn_type will be called?

Many thanks.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Obviously 'payment failed, will retry' will precede 'payment failed, subscription terminated'.