# Paypal's behavior on failed/missing payment of Subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am working on a Website or can say a Payment Portal in which users can Subscribe some of services using Paypal Subscription, and administrator can manage all Subscriptions,

I am using Paypal Subscription API for this, which documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/

All is going well, but confused with a thing like:

Suppose there is a Subscription Profile with 12 Monthly Cycle, So it will charge customer every month, Suppose first 2 payments charged successfully, but 3rd payment is missed/failed due to any reason, then **how** and **when** Paypal try to collect this missed payment, and if all failed attempt what will be the status of Subscription, if Subscription Plan have:

1) `payment_failure_threshold` is 0,

2) `payment_failure_threshold` is 1,

3) `payment_failure_threshold` is 2,

I checked about `payment_failure_threshold`

I checked on Paypal about this case here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/reattempt-failed-payment/

But it does not state about `payment_failure_threshold`.

[API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-payment_preferences) said this about `payment_failure_threshold`:

[image]

But I still confused with the different values of `payment_failure_threshold`.

Please help me to find out the behavior of failed payment retry with its different values. Explanation via some example with date (when and how much time Paypal will retry, and on all failed attempt what will be the status of Subscription) will helpful for me,

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I asked a question at Paypal Merchant Technical Support about `Missing Payment Retry Process`, So first, they answered this:

[image]

Then I gave referenced of this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/reattempt-failed-payment/), then they guys answered this:

[image]

And it's almost a month, and they didn't update their docs.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this on Paypal Developer Documentation

> PayPal reattempts a recurring payment three days after the recurring
> payment failed. If this first reattempt fails, PayPal waits 5 days to
> reattempt a second time. If the second reattempt fails, PayPal cancels
> the subscription.

Comment: I already mentioned this link in question, also its heading is `Reattempt failed recurring payments with Subscribe buttons`, I think it is specifically for Subscribe buttons not for Subscription API

Answer (score 0):

so basically payment_failure_threshold states for how many sub cycles can be failed.
Let's say you have sub started on 4th Feb with 1 month cycle plan and payment_failure_threshold is set to 2. The payment during sub creation was succesful.
Paypal is gonna try to rebill sub on 4th of March. If it fails, it's gonna try again twice 5, 10 days later. If it fails on 14th of March it's gonna raise failed attempts (for charging cycles) from 0 to 1.
Then paypal is gonna try again to rebill it on 4th of August. If it fails, it's gonna try again twice 5, 10 days later. If it fails on 14th of August it's gonna raise failed attempts (for charging cycles) from 1 to 2.
Failed paid cycles reached threshold so sub is going to be suspended. Up to this point sub was active and the money customer owes for sub is added to his outstanding balance.
You can suspend user sub via api if you wish.
You can activate it, let's say on 3rd of May via api. Paypal is gonna try to collect money on 4th of May.
You can try to collect outstanding money via api.
An example can be found here, although here they say that failed paid cycles must exceed payment_failure_threshold for the sub to be suspended:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/subscriptions/add-capabilities/payment-failure-retry/
while here they say that it can be just equal:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

> For example, if payment_failure_threshold is 2, the subscription automatically updates to the SUSPEND state if two consecutive payments fail.

But this can be easily checked in their sandbox.